# Using mod_rewrite to bypass an "invalid SSL cert" error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a certificate that is registered to the fully qualified domain name of a server on our intranet (webserver.domain.com).  When our internal users hit this site via the fully qualified name, they go right in and aren't prompted that it's an invalid cert.   If they browse to the web server via the hostname (non-fully qualified) they are redirected to the https version and no prompt is made there either.   The part of my mod_rewrite that I'm missing is if someone connects to the web server via http's' with just the hostname.  I can't seem to get that to rewrite to the FQDN.  It doesn't rewrite and always prompts that the cert is invalid.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Here's an example of what I can't seem to match:
http**s**://webserver/pubs/index.html

I need it to rewrite to: 
http**s**://webserver.**domain.com**/pubs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't going to be possible - the prompt occurs when the connection is made, before mod_rewrite is involved.

If they OK the prompt, then you can rewrite to the FQDN.